# Solving LeetCode #13 Roman to Integer Question (Char comparison)

Tags: string, char, comparison

Here is the problem link: https://leetcode.com/problems/roman-to-integer/

I kept having problem on comparison s.charAt() and a char of Roman.
I am very new to JAVA. Isn't if(s.charAt(i) == 'I') supposed to work?
I saw other solutions of this problem, but the solutions tend to make a char and put the char of string in that char.
Could you please explain why my comparison is not working?
I really appreciate your answer in advance.

class Solution {

```
public int romanToInt(String s) {
    int i = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    
    for(i=0;i<s.length();i++)
    {
        if(s.charAt(i) == 'I')
        {
            if(s.charAt(i+1) == 'X') //4
            {
                i++;
                sum += 4;
            }
            else if(s.charAt(i+1) == 'V') //9
            {
                i++;
                sum += 9;
            }
            else
            {
                sum += 1;
            }
                
        }
        else if(s.charAt(i) == 'V')
        {
            sum += 10;
        }
        else if(s.charAt(i) == 'X')
        {
            if(s.charAt(i+1) == 'L') //40
            {
                i++;
                sum += 40;
            }
            else if(s.charAt(i+1) == 'C') //90
            {
                i++;
                sum += 90;
            }
            else
            {
                sum += 10;
            }
        }
        else if(s.charAt(i) == 'L')
        {
            sum += 50;
        }
        else if(s.charAt(i) == 'C')
        {
            if(s.charAt(i+1) == 'D') //400
            {
                i++;
                sum += 400;
            }
            else if(s.charAt(i+1) == 'M') //900
            {
                i++;
                sum += 900;
            }
            else
            {
                sum+=100;
            }
        }
        else if(s.charAt(i) == 'D')
        {
            sum += 500;
        }
        else if(s.charAt(i) == 'M')
        {
            sum += 1000;
        }
            
    }
    return sum;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I used Java for this:

```
public int romanToInt(String s) {
    
    HashMap<Character, Integer> dict = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    {
    dict.put('I', 1);
    dict.put('V', 5);
    dict.put('X', 10);
    dict.put('L', 50);
    dict.put('C', 100);
    dict.put('D', 500);
    dict.put('M', 1000);
    }        
    int temp = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
        char c= s.charAt(i);
        temp += dict.get(c);
        char d= '.';
        if((i+1)<s.length() && d!=c){
            d = s.charAt(i+1);
    
        if((c=='I' && (d=='V' || d=='X')) ||
           (c=='X' && (d=='L' || d=='C')) || 
            (c=='C' && (d=='D' || d=='M')))
            {
            temp += dict.get(d)-2*dict.get(c);
            i++;
             }
        }  
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).